# Images or Attachments are not deleting from folder in server

Tags: php

I am using the codeigniter.I am storing the files in json modal in db.When i am deleting the files form view i am able to delete from Db and view but i am unable to unlink the file from folder .Can you please helpout the mistake what i done.I am very thankful .

**controller code**:

```
   public function deleteEventAttachments($patientId,$id,$index)
{
    //print_r($patientId.$id.$index);
    $eventdata=$this->objPatients->get_Events($id)[0];
    $attachments=json_decode($eventdata->eventAttachments);
    $attach=array();
    $deletefile="";
    foreach ($attachments as $key => $value) {
        if ($key!=$index){
            $attach[]=$value;
        }
        if($key==$index  && $value!=""){
            $deletefile=$value;
            unlink(base_url().'resources/patients/attachments/'.$deletefile);
        }   
    }
    $files=json_encode($attach);
    $eData= array('eventAttachments' => $files);
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->update('patients_events',$eData);
    redirect(base_url().'patients/editPatient/'.$patientId.'/?tab=events'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the mode of the file and it`s folders.